# Why does puppeteer not render this page correctly when it takes a screenshot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

This code uses the Node.JS library [`puppeteer`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) to take a screenshot of a web page and save it as a png image:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox', '--incognito']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);
    page.on('request', request => {
        if (request.resourceType() === 'script')
        request.abort();
        else
        request.continue();
    });
    await page.goto(process.argv[2], { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    await page.screenshot({path: process.argv[3], fullPage: true });
    await browser.close();
```

The script is run like this:

```
nodejs screenshot-webpage.js "https://www.washingtonpost.com/sports/nationals/the-astros-are-back-in-this-world-series-and-the-chess-game-is-officially-afoot/2019/10/26/ad6739c4-f75f-11e9-ad8b-85e2aa00b5ce_story.html" "filename-for-screenshot.png"
```

Can anyone replicate the broken screenshot that's shown below?

The Node.JS script ignores Javascript elements, which is by design, but if I view the page in a web browser with Javascript disabled, it looks correct

Is there something wrong with my puppeteer script? I'm using Node.JS v12.13.0 on a Debian 9 x64 system. The script successfully takes screenshots of other web pages, so I'm not sure if it's the script itself or something about how the script interacts with this particular webpage.

The screenshot looks like this (image cropped to the top of the page to fit it into the question):

---

## Broken screenshot

---

[image: broken screenshot of Washington Post page]

---

## Correct screenshot

---

:

[image: proper screenshot of Washington Post]

Answer (score 1):

I've put some test to your script and modify it for you a little bit.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        // headless: false,
        devtools: false,
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--incognito']
    })
    const page = (await browser.pages())[0]
    await page.setRequestInterception(true)

    let cssNum = 0
    console.log ('\n\nList of CSS loaded:\n')
    page.on('request', request => {
        if (request.resourceType() === 'script'){
            request.abort()
        } else {
            request.continue()
        }
        if (request.resourceType() === 'stylesheet'){
            cssNum++
            console.log (`[${cssNum}] => ${request.url()}`)
        }
    });

    await page.goto(process.argv[2], { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
    await page.screenshot({
        type: 'png',
        path: process.argv[3],
        fullPage: true
    })
    await browser.close()
    console.log('\n\n')
})()
```

Added some debugging settings, such as headless and devtools in `puppeteer.launch`.
For the first run, the headless is set to false, and it works well.

[[640px x 9726px, 685KBs] It works smoothly and fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXkz6.jpg)

And when i set the `{headless : true}` or set it as comment (default true when use puppeteer), the screenshot was ugly as you said before.

[[624px × 8898px, 720KBs] Screenshot is ugly and layout is bad formatted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3INEh.jpg)

I think Washington Posts website detecting headless browser and differentiating the results of the response. As you can see the image below, the stylesheets are different URLs.

[[847px x 405px, 54KBs] Terminal Console.logs show the differences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYL62.png)

And now, you can always set the default puppeteer launch to `{headless : false}`.

Also you should add the headless args to be set in the command line, so you can runs and add options in terminal easily both headless true or false.